# Using Moment Timezone in Javascript Analog Clock

Tags: javascript

Can't get moment timezone to work on an analog clock. Want to get clock to show Los Angeles time. Clock works fine with "new Date()" rather than "moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles")". Libraries are functional when using text format clock.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGNWpr)

JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
ctx.clearRect(-radius, -radius, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
var ang;
var num;
ctx.font = 14 + "px arial";
ctx.textBaseline="middle";
ctx.textAlign="center";
for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.80);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.80);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
var timestamp = moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var hour = timestamp.getHours();
var minute = timestamp.getMinutes();
var second = timestamp.getSeconds();
//hour
hour=hour%12;
hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
(minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
(second*Math.PI/(360*60));
drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
//minute
minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.7, radius*0.07);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = width;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.rotate(pos);ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When use `moment` the functions you are looking for are not `getHours`, `getMinutes`, `getSeconds`, but only `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`:

```
var timestamp = moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var hour = timestamp.hours();
var minute = timestamp.minutes();
var second = timestamp.seconds();
```

Here is the update to your code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
 ctx.clearRect(-radius, -radius, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
 drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
 var ang;
 var num;
 ctx.font = 14 + "px arial";
 ctx.textBaseline="middle";
 ctx.textAlign="center";
 for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
  ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
  ctx.rotate(ang);
  ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.80);
  ctx.rotate(-ang);
  ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(ang);
  ctx.translate(0, radius*0.80);
  ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
 var timestamp = new Date();
  var timestamp = moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles");;
 var hour = timestamp.hours();
 var minute = timestamp.minutes();
 var second = timestamp.seconds();
 //hour
 hour=hour%12;
 hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
 (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
 (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
 drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
 //minute
 minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
 drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.7, radius*0.07);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = width;
 ctx.lineCap = "round";
 ctx.moveTo(0,0);
 ctx.rotate(pos);ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="clock" height="114" width="114"></canvas>
```